# Flaw in the listing of related questions?

Tags: bug

I just wrote a question at [Could students be taught the concept of rational numbers the same way as in the Formal construction section of the Wikipedia article rational number?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15469/could-students-be-taught-the-concept-of-rational-numbers-the-same-way-as-in-the) and wrote the word field in that question. The question at [How does a student learn to 'dig behind the scenes' or 'feel' math like a Fields Medallist?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11950/how-does-a-student-learn-to-dig-behind-the-scenes-or-feel-math-like-a-fields) was listed as related to that question and it was probably because it had the word field in it but it's a completely different definition of the word "field."

Comment: Related (hah!) on Meta SE: [How are “related” questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/241919). In short, it's just a simple search, not taking different definitions of a word into a consideration.

Comment: All due respect to the programmers behind the scenes, 'related' is the weakest link (pun intended) on the site. I, too often, see a related question that's already been closed, and find that a distraction.